# Install TensorFlow latest build using Mamba

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, mamba

I want to use `mamba install` to install the latest TensorFlow distribution (2.10 or 2.9.1 at least) with CUDA enabled.
I tried the following:

```
mamba install -c anaconda tensorflow==2.9.1=gpu_py310*
```

```
mamba install -c anaconda tensorflow=2.9.1=gpu_py310*
```

```
mamba install -c anaconda tensorflow=2.9.1=gpu_py310
```

```
mamba install tensorflow-gpu
```

The output is generally:

```
anaconda/win-64                                             Using cache
anaconda/noarch                                             Using cache
conda-forge/win-64                                          Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested tensorflow
```

With `2.9.1` and `gpu_py310*` if also on input command. It's important to clarify that I ***don't want to use pip***, I want mamba to manage packages nicely to me. Any suggestions or answers to this problem?

Comment: "*None of those worked...*" - how do they fail? Problem could be the '*' is evaluated by the shell. Have you tried `mamba install -c anaconda 'tensorflow=2.9.1=gpu_py310*'`?

Comment: @merv Just tried that, it worked!
If you want to put as an answer, I will accept it. EDIT: Nevermind, it didn't.

Comment: @merv the error is ```- nothing provides requested tensorflow 2.9.1 gpu_py310*```

Comment: Works fine for me - both **win-64** and **linux-64** subdirs. And I can replicate your issue if I leave out the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured  it out, just had to use `-c main` instead of `-c anaconda`. The command is as follows:

```
mamba install -c main tensorflow==2.9.1=gpu_py310*
```

It installs the desired version.

Comment: That’s surprising! I always thought they were aliases for the same channel.